# Pass Environment Variable to Sudo AWS ec2 sudo node

Tags: sudo, environment-variables, amazon-ec2, node.js

I am new to linux and AWS.  I have a node.js server running on an EC2 instance. I am running the following command to keep it running endlessly and on port 80:

```
 $ sudo node app.js &
```

Now when I run it using `sudo` my node application will not find any of the environment variables.

I need to be able to set environment variable USER, PASSWORD, and an IP to connect to my database.  I have tried countless commands and only managed to set 1 environment variable but it gets deleted when I set a new variable.

**SOLUTION**

I found what I was looking for thanks to the example Jeff Schaller gave below. I tried it exactly as it was but I'm not sure why it didn't work,  I ended up learning a bit on shellscripts.

First I ran `$ vim runapp.sh`.  Then I added the following code :

```
#!/bin/sh
Clear
export USER="Username"
export PASSWORD="Password"
export IP="1.1.1.1"
Node ./bin/www
```

After I saved the file, I ran `$ chmod +x runapp.sh`

Finally I ran `$ sudo ./runapp.sh &` and it ran perfectly.

If I should not be doing this or if there is an error or a better and safer way of doing it let me know so that I can fix it eventually.

Comment: You might try: `sudo USER=... PASSWORD=... node app.js`.  This sets the environment variables just for the forked process, and hopefully in a way that `sudo` will allow.

Comment: Just wrap the vars in a shell script, then sudo the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
USER=u PASSWORD=p IP=10.10.10.10 node app.js
```

... or ...

```
#!/bin/sh
USER=u; export USER
PASSWORD=p; export PASSWORD
IP=10.10.10.10; export IP
node app.js
```

... where you put your own values in there instead of "u", "p", and "10.10.10.10". Save the file as, say, `runapp`, then make it executable with `chmod u+x runapp`, then you run it:

```
sudo ./runapp &
```

Comment: As a side note, unless you have a nopasswd flag in your sudo config, I'd recommend running something like `sudo -l` before trying to run a sudo command in the background -- just so that you can send your password to the sudo prompt.